# My pc screen keeps starting up with Check signal cable

Tags: signal, av-cable

My pc screen keeps starting up with Check signal cable. What does this mean and What can I do?

Thanks

Bev

Answer (score 1):

Generally "Check signal cable" is a warning displayed by your monitor.
It means that the monitor is not receiving signal from your graphics card.
It could be anything from a hardware failure to simply a loose cable. Make sure the ends of the cable are tightly connected to your PC and monitor.

This problem has many potential causes. Please add more detail to your question.
What is the PC Speaker beep code, if any?
Have you done any hardware changes in the past?
Is this a desktop or a laptop computer?